# Unmounting /usr from an external drive

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, arm, unmounting

I mounted `/usr` from the nvidia TX1 dev board to an external SSD connected to the board.

I am wondering how I can restore it original state without re-flashing?  If I power down,and disconnect the SSD, and start, there will be no /usr directory.

I was thinking of making a copy to /root/usr and updating `fstab` to point to that instead of the external SSD, but there has to be a better option, I just cant think of it at the moment.

If it were a regular `x86` I'd just boot to a live CD and fix it, but this is an SoC with Arm, so it's not quite that easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bind mount of `/` to make the original `/usr` (which should probably be empty there if `/usr` was mounted over it before `/usr` was ever populated) available and copy the mounted `/usr` over it.

```
# mkdir /root/underlyingroot
# mount --bind --make-private / /root/underlyingroot
# cp -ax /usr /root/underlyingroot
# umount /root/underlyingroot
```

`--make-private` is to cancel the case where `/` is mounted with the [`shared` option](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt?h=v4.19.19#n39), which [it is when running `systemd`](https://serverfault.com/questions/868682/implications-of-mount-make-private/868735#868735). Else anything mounted (eg: automount of an inserted device etc.) between the `mount` and `umount` above will be reflected inside `/root/underlyingroot` and prevent the simple `umount /root/underlyingroot` working after.

Now that the copy is done at the final place you can edit `/etc/fstab` and remove the `/usr` mountpoint.

If nothing at all running is using `/usr` you might be able to also `umount` immediately `/usr` and be done. But nowadays it's hard to have things running not using `/usr` at all if not in single user or rescue mode and today not even even always (eg newer CentOS), so a reboot is probably needed anyway. You can also consider `umount --lazy /usr` which would allow to immediately get rid of `/usr` and have any new updates to `/usr` done on the internal storage instead of external, but external would still be required until next reboot.